# How to set up ServiceBusTrigger with Dependency Injection with .Net Core 6.0 Isolated

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics, asp.net-core-6.0

I currently have a  ServiceBus Trigger in .Net Core 6.0 Isolated.  Trying to figure out how to Use Dependency Injection,  to set up the Trigger.   Trying to figure out how to do this with .Net Core 6.0 Isolated.
I have a strongly typed model that is Bound to the appsettings.json file in the Program.cs code.  That part works and has been verified. However when trying to do this with .Net Core 6 Isolated It give error about missing reference.

Here's my Config model that is bound to the appsettings.json file.  I have left out the appsettings.json file for simplification

```
    public  class MyConfig
{
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the  Service bus trigger class

```
public class ServiceBusTriggerClass
{
  
    private readonly MyConfig _myConfig;

    public ServiceBusTriggerClass(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
    {
        _myConfig= config.Value;
    }

 
    [Function("MySBFunction")]
    public async Task MySBFunction([ServiceBusTrigger(_myConfig.Topic, _myConfig.SubscriptionName)] object myObject)
    {
 // Do things with the myObject thing. 
        
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible on .net 8 isolated

From a "Service Bus Trigger" example in Visual studio

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ServiceBusExample
{
    public class TestSBFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TestSBFunction> _logger;

        public TestSBFunction(ILogger<TestSBFunction> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(TestSBFunction))]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "blah")]
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

            // Complete the message
            await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 1-13-2022 it is not possible to do this Using .Net 6 Isolated function. The function does not have access to the Host at this point.